# Windows 10 dialog "Ask for permission" even though I am the admin account

Tags: windows-10, permissions

Windows 10 Home. I setup family safety years ago. After a random update a while ago (can't quite remember) a dialog "You’ll need to ask an adult in your family if you can use: - Microsoft Sticky Notes" appears every time I fresh boot my PC and log into the parent (also admin) account. No other account, even the children, has this issue.

Trace ID: 2S6baCQs+0K/jnPS.3 (PrdID:9NBLGGH4QGHW)

Any ideas?

Edit: Parents can't have restrictions set in parental controls on family safety.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in Windows 10 that has been reported over a year a ago and still hasn't been solved.

According to https://www.surfacetablethelp.com/2018/06/microsoft-family-ask-for-permission-to-use-shell-experience-and-chrome-in-windows-10.html, deleting the contents of the folder c:\windows\system32\applocker fixes the issue. But possibly only temporarily.

Other suggested that uninstalling the offending app (in your case Microsoft Sticky Notes) fixed it for them.

Comment: ooh, good idea, I'll try it at let you know. At least someone understood the problem!

Comment: Followed this guide, will update you when I next restart
https://www.top-password.com/blog/uninstall-or-reinstall-sticky-notes-in-windows-10/

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/what-is-windows-shell-experience-and-why-do-i-get/68d79375-44c8-40e1-ae0a-1c576eb7b31d

Comment: It worked! Clearing the AppLocker folder is exactly the solution. Thanks Bart!

Comment: Funnily enough I got downvoted on this answer by someone, although it solved the problem on my machine and now confirmed to fix it for @Dorjan 

Answer (score 3):

Parental Controls are not the same as Administrator security settings.

In order to stop this, Ask the person who setup the block to login with their account to lift the restrictions.

Comment: What do you mean? I setup the family safety, and I'm the parent in that family

Comment: Then you should be able to setup the permissions to disable it in Parental Controls.

Comment: I'm sure what you said makes sense for someone who knows the answer but why are there any restrictions on software on a parent's account and none of the others and where would you go to lift the restrictions? (Or even set them?)

Comment: In case you're unaware, parents can't have restrictions in Parental Controls, so I'm not sure what you're suggesting. Please clarify